# Average of a random sample drawn from two variables

Tags: random-variables, variance, binomial-distribution, sampling

I have two independent random variables $x_1$ and $x_2$, mean $0$ and standard deviation $1$. I want to draw 1 samples from each and take the weighted average. If the weight is a fixed number, I can easily calculate the variance of the average (i.e. var($w_1$*$x_1$+$w_2$*$x_2$). However, now instead of always fixing the weight, I now use a distribution to determine the multiple for each variable:

Case 1: Uniform distribution, so 0 to N from $x_1$ (the renaming from $x_2$) all with the same prob

Case 2: Binomial with $p=0.5$, B*$x_1$ + (N-B)*$x_2$

Now I want to calculate the variance of the sample average under these two cases. My intuition is that it should be bigger because another layer of randomness is added. But I am having a hard time deriving the solution. Thanks!

Comment: I don't understand how your random samples work. If $N = 10$ and you end up drawing $3$ samples from $X_1$ and $7$ samples from $X_2$, then don't we just end up with 10 independent samples from $N(0,1)$? Or are you saying that the 3 samples from $X_1$ will all have the same value as each other and likewise for the 7 samples from $X_2$? Or do you mean something else? Please edit the question to make it clearer.

Comment: @DavidClyde right, I meant draw X1 and X2 once, but multiple them by 3 and 7 respectively

Comment: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/319173/variance-of-weighted-average-when-weights-have-a-distribution  looks like this post gives me what i need to derive it